# How to set the data of chart in angular which is taken from the backend nodejs api that is store in mongodb and showing on the html page

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, chart.js, ng2-charts

**app.component.html**
*This is my app.component file where i show my chart*

```
    <div style="display: block;">
         <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                    [datasets]="lineChartData"
                    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                    [options]="lineChartOptions"
                    [colors]="lineChartColors"
                    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                    [chartType]="lineChartType">
         </canvas>
     </div>
```

**app.component.ts**
*My ts file where the logic impleneted i have issue there i am not know how to perform logic to show the data i have issue how to create method in it which will call in the app.component.html file*

```
   constructor(private chartService: ChartServiceService) { }
    
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getlinechart();
   }
 getlinechart(){
     this.chartService.getLineChart().subscribe(res => {
     this.linechart = res;
     console.log(res);

     let lincechartData = res.list[0].data;
     let lincechartLabels =  res.list[0].graphlabels;
  
     public lineChartData:any = this.lincechartData;
      **I,m facing issue here above to create method to store the 
        data and used in html compiler give the error this ,' 
 expected.ts(1005)
 Cannot find name 'lineChartData'**
  
});
```

}
**app.service.ts**
*This is service file which getting the data from the backend nodejs api*

```
  getLineChart(){
       return this.httpClient.get<any> 
        ('http://localhost:3000/api/chart/line')
      .pipe(
        map(result => result)
      )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If i undestand correctly you are trying to read data from a database and put it on a chart. I did something similar, but i had a bit different approach:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="100"></canvas> <br/>
```

**Chart config:**

```
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: { datasets: [] }, // trend data goes here
    options: { 
        scales: {
            xAxis: { // x axis
                type: 'time',
            }
        },
    },
}
```

**New chart:**

```
function newChart() {
     config.data.datasets = []; // reset data
     populateTrend(config); // populate chart

     if (window.hasOwnProperty("graph")) { // destroy previous chart
          if (typeof window.graph.resetZoom !== "undefined") { // if you have a zoom plugin
               window.graph.resetZoom();
          }
          window.graph.destroy();
     }

     let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); // canvas
     window.graph = new Chart(ctx, config); // make the chart
}
```

**populate trend:**

```
function populateTrend (config) {
    // data sets and scales
    let datasets = config.data.datasets, scales = config.options.scales;

    let log = data; // this is where you read from your database

    let dataset = { // add some data here
        data: [],
        label: log.description, 
        fill: false, 
        radius: 0,
        unit: log.unit, 
        pointType: log.pointType,
        yAxisID: log.unit, // y axis
    };

    // this is where the real data goes
    // you should push the data in a loop
    dataset.data.push({
        "x": something.getTime(),
        "y": null,
        "ymin": null,
        "ymax": null,
    });

    datasets.push(dataset); // add data set to config
}
```

Comment: where is response that we getting from the backend and also subscribe method

Comment: It is little bit confusing me ?

Comment: @AmirShahzad Are you having problems getting or showing the data?? i'm simply showing how to show the data. The populateTrend function is just a skeleton for you to put your data in. it doesn't have any data the way it currently is

Comment: i am begginer in angular therefore im facing problem to handle therse satuations. i want to resolve this problm but i could not understand your answer

Comment: @AmirShahzad you didn't answer my question at all. Are you trying to **get**  new data from your database or are you trying to **show** the data that you already have?